# django queryset filter in list with null

Tags: django-queryset

I'm trying to create a query to generate a query set and I want the query to search for a list of values including when the field is NULL. Normally one would do something like:

search_query = search_query & (Q(class_*field*_in=["a", "b"]) | Q(class_*field*_isnull=True))

However in this case I wish to pass in a list of values to generate the list i.e.

search_query = search_query & Q(class_*field*_in=[x for x in alist])

This way I can decouple what values are passed in dependent on form input. I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to represent Q(class_*field*_isnull=True) as a variable that I can pass in. I have tried None, "None", "" and "NULL" without success. Is this even possible and if so does anyone know how? Or am I going about things the wrong way?

Many thanks as ever.

Comment: Seems like a bug. `__in` does not work in 2021 for `None`

Answer (score 0):

Why not make it in a different way:

```
for x in aslist:
   query = query & Q(class_field=x)
query = query & Q(class_field__isnull=True)
```

or even like this:

```
q = list()
for x in aslist:
   q.append(Q(class_field=x))
q.append(Q(class_field__isnull=True))
query=reduce(operator.or_,q)
```