# Django Query __isnull=True or = None

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

this is a simple question. I'd like to know if it is the same to write:

```
queryset = Model.objects.filter(field=None)
```

than:

```
queryset = Model.objects.filter(field__isnull=True)
```

I'm using django 1.8

Answer (score 71, accepted):

They are equal:

```
>>> str(Person.objects.filter(age__isnull=True).query) == str(Person.objects.filter(age=None).query)
True
>>> print(Person.objects.filter(age=None).query)
SELECT "person_person"."id", "person_person"."name", "person_person"."yes", "person_person"."age" FROM "person_person" WHERE "person_person"."age" IS NULL
>>> print(Person.objects.filter(age__isnull=True).query)
SELECT "person_person"."id", "person_person"."name", "person_person"."yes", "person_person"."age" FROM "person_person" WHERE "person_person"."age" IS NULL
```

Exclusion: the Postgres JSON field (see the answer of @cameron-lee)

Comment: Just wondering if using `field__isnull=True' is not faster than `field=None` I imagine,  isnull would be faster as it seems to match the database

Comment: @unlockme: well they result in the *same* query: Django ORM is smart enough to use `IS NULL`, hence except for some small difference due to the handling of this `=None`, vs `__isnull=True` when *translating* the call in a query, the two run in the same time.

Comment: I've had some issues with using __in and None. Such as: __in=(None, "", " ") will result to False while Q(__isnull=True)|Q(__in=("", " ")) would result to True. Could never truly figure out why.

Comment: @Dougyfresh seems like a Django bug - quoted here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20225340/django-queryset-filter-in-list-with-null

Comment: @Anupam, this is not a bug. Null does not compare as true to any value including null. For example, "select null = null;" will return null, not true. "select null in [1, 2, null]" will return false. The only way to test if something is null is to use "is null".

Answer (score 53):

It depends on the type of field. As mentioned in other answers, they are usually equivalent but in general, this isn't guaranteed.

For example, the Postgres JSON field uses `=None` to specify that the json has the value `null` while `__isnull=True` means there is no json:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield

[image: null json vs no json]

Comment: Really great answer! Love it

Comment: I am currently having a hard time matching "None" Postgres JSON fields. Neither filter(field__is_null=True) or filter(field=None) are working. How would I match for these null postgres JSON fields?

Comment: @thrillhouse: it sounds like maybe you have stored the string "None" which is different than both SQL null or json null.

Answer (score 38):

Just to keep in mind that you cannot reverse the condition with your first solution:

```
# YOU CANNOT DO THIS
queryset = Model.objects.filter(field!=None)
```

However you can do this:

```
queryset = Model.objects.filter(field__isnull=False)
```

Comment: You can do `.exclude(field=None)` if you need to reverse the condition - personally I prefer `.exclude` because it is more explicit.

Comment: However every time you do that you wrap the query, and multiple query wrappings, if unnecessary, can be cumbersome SQL-wise and even slow down performance @PauloScardine

Comment: Interesting, @wonderwhy do you have a source for the "performance slowdown" due to wrappings? I never had any performance glitch with PostgreSQL due to multiple wrappings - in my experience the planner does a very good job with this kind of query. About the query being cumbersome SQL-wise the whole point of using an ORM is not having to deal with SQL - I could not care less about the automatically generated SQL as long as it performs well... :-)

Comment: rather a comment

Comment: You could do `~Q(field=None)`, which effectively means `field is not None`. Not saying it's the best way, it's just a way.